# is training rasa based on session user active?

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-sdk

im a freshman on rasa (chatbot).
i am using rasa Version 2.2 with botfront for admin panel.
my project was deployed and publish in development area (restricted user on my work only) in 3 last days.

my question :

1. when i train rasa in botfront apps and see the log on server, he will train based on session user. is it like that ?
   here my log on server

```
2023-02-08 06:23:36 DEBUG    rasa_addons.core.channels.webchat  - User BMkLfyfz-39wX1NPAAit connected to socketIO endpoint.
2023-02-08 06:23:42 DEBUG    rasa.utils.tensorflow.models  - Finished building tensorflow prediction graph.
2023-02-08 06:23:42 DEBUG    rasa.core.nlg.generator  - Instantiated NLG to 'GraphQLNaturalLanguageGenerator'.

2023-02-08 06:23:42 DEBUG    rasa.server  -Successfully loaded model 'model-5pcXs4w7mJuwRH5C7.tar.gz'.

Epochs:  18%|█▊        | 9/50 [04:05<17:36, 25.78s/it, t_loss=1.653, loss=0.690, acc=0.998]2023-02-08 06:24:00 DEBUG    rasa_addons.core.channels.webchat  - User tRpkKF7BlMZm8PNPAAip disconnected from socketIO endpoint.
2023-02-08 06:24:03 DEBUG    rasa_addons.core.channels.webchat  - User l4aoVZpt-xzfb6pvAAiv connected to socketIO endpoint.
2023-02-08 06:24:04 DEBUG    rasa_addons.core.channels.graphql  - fetching endpoints and credentials at http://botfront-app:3000/graphql
2023-02-08 06:24:04 DEBUG    rasa_addons.core.channels.webchat  - User l4aoVZpt-xzfb6pvAAiv connected to socketIO endpoint.

Epochs:  22%|██▏       | 11/50 [04:36<13:15, 20.39s/it, t_loss=1.371, loss=0.427, acc=0.998]2023-02-08 06:24:37 DEBUG    rasa_addons.core.channels.webchat  - User f2Jmi43Qv656OJTAAAix connected to socketIO endpoint.

2023-02-08 06:24:37 DEBUG    rasa_addons.core.channels.graphql  - fetching endpoints and credentials at http://botfront-app:3000/graphql
Epochs:  24%|██▍       | 12/50 [04:50<11:49, 18.67s/it, t_loss=1.275, loss=0.343, acc=0.999]2023-02-08 06:24:37 DEBUG    rasa_addons.core.channels.webchat  - User f2Jmi43Qv656OJTAAAix connected to socketIO endpoint.

Epochs:  30%|███       | 15/50 [05:34<09:10, 15.73s/it, t_loss=1.094, loss=0.194, acc=0.999]2023-02-08 06:25:23 DEBUG    rasa_addons.core.channels.webchat  - User l4aoVZpt-xzfb6pvAAiv disconnected from socketIO endpoint.
```

and many more epoch process on different user session.
on the log, he's already done train and load the model.

2. if yes, how can i train this core without based on session server ?

my expect, train in the same time when the endpoint rasa is published and accessing from user.

Comment: Do you want to deploy a pre-trained model (trained by you)?

Comment: yep, i want to deploy by me. anw, is rasa can learn without i train (manual train) ?

Comment: If you can, please clarify your specific problem and what you need. As it's not very clear what you mean.